# Написать декоратор

Tags: python, декоратор

декоратор должен записывать в файл  во сколько начала отрабатывать декорируемая функция и во сколько закончила

Comment: Да, конечно. Вот вам в помощь хорошая ссылка: <https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/dekoratory-python/> Изучите её и примеры в ней, и пишите функцию. Работать со временем поможет модуль `time`. Вот ещё ссылка в помощь: <https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-time-python/funktsija-time-modulja-time/> Удачи!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

oksdfj() - функция которую мы записываем

nachalo() - функция которая вызывается в начале функции oksdfj() и записывает время и дату в файл log.txt (Не забудь создать файл)

konec() - функция которая вызывается в конце функции oksdfj() и записывает время и дату в файл log.txt

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def nachalo():
    current_datetime1 = datetime.now() 
    print(current_datetime1)
    f = open('log.txt', 'a')
    f.write(str(current_datetime1) + "\n")
    f.close()

def konec():
    current_datetime1 = datetime.now() 
    print(current_datetime1)
    f = open('log.txt', 'a')
    f.write(str(current_datetime1) + "\n")
    f.close()

def oksdfj(): 
    nachalo()
    print("funcia delaet chto-to - 0")
    time.sleep(1) 
    print("funcia delaet chto-to - 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("funcia delaet chto-to - 2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("funcia delaet chto-to - 3")
    konec()
oksdfj()
```

Comment: в Python есть специальная конструкция дял декораторов в виде мета-атрибута к функции/классу... благодаря чему не нужно писать код декоратора с используемой функцией — просто описывается декоратор, а над используемой функцией он указывается через `@my_decorator`. Так можно декорировать ЛЮБУЮ функцию, тогда как ваш пример сделан без особенностей Python и для каждого использования нужно писать новую функции-обертки

Answer (score -1):

[Декоратор](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/dekoratory-python/) - функция, которая оборачивает другую функцию, добавляя ей желаемое поведение.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import time


# декорируемая функция
def timer():
    print("0")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3")


# декоратор
def timer_logger():
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as file:
        timer_logger_start(file)
        timer()
        timer_logger_end(file)


# начало декоратора
def timer_logger_start(file):
    file.write(str(datetime.now()) + "\n")


# конец декоратора
def timer_logger_end(file):
    file.write(str(datetime.now()) + "\n")


# точка входа в программу
if __name__ == '__main__':
    timer_logger()
```